# Who hired the hit squad that disrupted Furlong's capture?

Tags: freejack

Near the beginning of [Freejack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freejack), Alex Furlong is pulled into the future by bonejackers.

But their plans to lobotomize (?) Furlong are disrupted when they come under fire from a hit squad, and Furlong is able to escape.

What was that hit squad trying to achieve?  Was it hired by any of the major players in the film?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Michelette hired the goons**

Michelette wanted to succeed Ian McCandless as head of the McCandless Corporation.  This would not happen for decades, if ever, if Ian McCandless survived by downloading himself into Furlong's body.  Therefore, Michelette hired the goons who repeatedly attempted to kill Furlong and/or interfere with Vacendak capturing him.  (Killing Furlong was Plan A, but Michelette could also achieve the same objective by preventing Furlong's capture until McCandless was out of time.)

Comment: Thanks Kerr, that makes sense!